# I need to print a table using "gridWrapper.innerHTML = gridWrapper.innerHTML+"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to print a table filling it with datas.
The problem is that as soon as I print the header of the table the tag  gets printed too and it doesn't allow me to insert any datas inside the table because I can't use .

The only thing that gets printed are the datas and the button that you can see in the for cycle

```
function elimina(id)
{
     var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');
     $.ajax({url: "selezioneProdotti.php", success: function(result)
     {
        console.log(result);
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        gridWrapper.innerHTML = " ";
        gridWrapper.innerHTML=gridWrapper.innerHTML+"<table><tr> 
        <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Prezzo</th><th>Elimina</th></tr>";
        for(var i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {           
            gridWrapper.innerHTML = gridWrapper.innerHTML+"<tr><td>"+ 
            result[i].nome+"</td><td>"+result[i].categoria+"</td> 
            <td>"+result[i].prezzo+"</td><td><a style='color:red'>&#x274C 
            Elimina</a></td></tr>";     
         }
         gridWrapper.innerHTML=gridWrapper.innerHTML+"</table>";
    }});
}
```

```
for(var i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {           
            gridWrapper.innerHTML = gridWrapper.innerHTML+"<tr><td>"+ 
            result[i].nome+"</td><td>"+result[i].categoria+"</td> 
            <td>"+result[i].prezzo+"</td><td><a style='color:red'>&#x274C 
            Elimina</a></td></tr>";     
         }
```

I want the table tag not to close before the table gets completly printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your function as below.
Here I have declared a temp variable which stores the inner html string and at last setting the inner Html property of element.

```html
function elimina(id)
{
     var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');
     $.ajax({url: "selezioneProdotti.php", success: function(result)
     {
        console.log(result);
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        gridWrapper.innerHTML = " ";
        var tableTemplate= "<table><tr> 
        <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Prezzo</th><th>Elimina</th></tr>";
        for(var i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {           
           tableTemplate = tableTemplate+"<tr><td>"+ 
            result[i].nome+"</td><td>"+result[i].categoria+"</td> 
            <td>"+result[i].prezzo+"</td><td><a style='color:red'>&#x274C 
            Elimina</a></td></tr>";     
         }
         
         tableTemplate=tableTemplate+"</table>";
         gridWrapper.innerHTML = tableTemplate;
    }});
}
```